# How to close popup on button press

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 and Angularjs. I can show the popup on a link press:

```
<p><a href="#" data-popup=".popup-mytest" class="open-popup">test popup</a></p>

<div class="popup popup-mytest">
    <div class="content-block">
          <p><a href="#" class="close-popup">Back</a></p>
          <p>My Popup1</p>
          <input type="text" ng-model="thename" >

         <a href="#" class="button button-fill button-big color-yellow" ng-click="process(thename)">Add Name</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to close the popup when I click on the Button.

In Angular scope I have:

```
$scope.process = function(thename){
    //add the name to db.
    //what script here to close the popup?
}
```

I can add the name to the db but just not able to close the popup.

**EDIT**
I want to close the button from the `$scope.process` as the validation is done in the process function and only on success I want to close the button. How do I pass something from the process function to close the button?

Also Im not using jQuery.

Please help.

Comment: Can you create a runnable snippet / Plunker of working pieces of code?

Comment: https://framework7.io/docs/popup.html#using-javascript `myApp.closeModal()` will do?

Comment: thanks @Icycool .. I want to close the button from the `$scope.process` as the validation is done in the process function and only on success I want to close the button. How do I pass something from the process function to close the button?

Comment: i suppose you init-ed fw7 somewhere in your code like `var myApp = new Framework7();`? If that's the case you can just write `myApp.closeModal()` in the process function

Comment: @Icycool .. I need to call the function in a controller, so closeModal not working in that controller. `myApp.closeModal is not a function` it says in the console

Comment: add `var myApp = new Framework7();` before `myApp.closeModal()`?

Comment: You rock @Icycool ... That worked! I hope that won't break any angular code in the future. Cause I never thought angular would allow defining fw app in a scope. Thanks a million Icycool .. you rock! You just made it very simple and without any hack.

Comment: Glad it works =) I think you should declare it as a global param or in a angular service so you don't have to new a framework every time you need to close a dialog though.

Comment: yeah .. will do that .. but thanks again .. how do i mark this as an answer? This is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

or from JS-

```
angular.element('#yourmodalID').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sumit. I want to close the button from the `$scope.process` as the validation is done in the process function and only on success I want to close the button. How do I pass something from the process function to close the button?

Comment: what exactly you are doing in process function?

Comment: Check if the user exists in DB, if yes, show error, if not, create user and close Popup. So on success i want to close the Popup. Thanks.

Comment: On success u can use this code-angular.element('#yourmodalID').modal('hide');

Comment: `Error: jqLite:nosel Unsupported Selector Lookup` so I did: `var div = document.querySelector('.popup-mytest');  
angular.element(mydiv).modal('hide');`  And now, im getting : 
`TypeError: angular.element(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery as it causes issues with Angular+FW7

Comment: Are you loading Jquery cdn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136733/discussion-between-somename-and-sumit-sinha).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
$('.popup-mytest').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using jQuery. Its AngularJS.

Comment: then try : angular.element('.popup-mytest').hide();

Comment: `Error: jqLite:nosel Unsupported Selector Lookup` so I did: `var div = document.getElementByClassName('.popup-mytest');  angular.element(mydiv).modal('hide');` And now, im getting : `TypeError: angular.element(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: can you set on variable to show/hide div using ng-if or ng-show like:

Comment: no. cause i want the form to be validated and only thn close the popup if success.

Comment: please create plunker